# What really is alignment on a longword boundary in the source code of memchr?

Tags: c, memory, libc

I've tried to understand and rewrite the memchr function but I found something strange at the beginning of the code.

We can read that:

```
#include "libc.h"
#include <unistd.h>

void    *my_memchr(void const *s, int c_in, size_t n)
{
    unsigned const char *char_ptr;
    unsigned char       c;
    /*
    ** t_longword is a typedef for unsigned long int **
                                                     */
    t_longword          *longword_ptr;
    t_longword          magic;
    t_longword          mega_c;

    c = (unsigned char)c_in;
    for (char_ptr = (unsigned const char*)s; n > 0
        && (size_t)char_ptr % sizeof(t_longword) != 0; --n, ++char_ptr)
    {
        if (*char_ptr == c)
            return ((void*)char_ptr);
    }
     longword_ptr = (t_longword*)char_ptr;
     print_bits(*longword_ptr);
     magic = 0x101010101010100; 
     mega_c = c | (c << 8);
     mega_c |= mega_c << 16;
     mega_c |= mega_c << 32;
/*
** I didn't finish to rewrite the entire function**
                                                 */
    return (NULL);
}
```

I was wondering why the first loop is mandatory ? I've already tried without in the function strlen and I've got some bugs from time to time but I don't know why.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The optimized part of `memchr()` requires that it work with a pointer that is four byte aligned.  However, there is no requirement that `s` as passed to the function is aligned in that way.

The purpose of that first loop is to advance `s` if necessary just far enough that it is correctly aligned for the optimized portion.  The loop is as complex as it is because it has to deal with two edge cases:

1. The character being searched for is in the first non-aligned few bytes, and
2. The case of the non-aligned starting area being so small that you reach the end of the buffer before getting the pointer aligned.

Comment: Yes but why it has to be aligned ? Why is it a problem to do the optimization without the alignment ?

Comment: On some hardware, unaligned reads of a 4 byte integer are slower than aligned reads.  On some other hardware (e.g. Motorola 68000) reading a 4 byte integer from an odd byte aligned pointer will crash the program.